# Customer Session is Empty In Custom Module

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, session, debugging

I have made a custom module which uses the customer session, but its strange, on live site its not returning customer data.

I have tried following methods:

```
$sessCustomer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
echo '<pre>';print_r($sessCustomer->getCustomer()->getData()); echo '</pre>';exit;
```

It returns:

```
Array
(
    [website_id] => 1
)
```

If I print the customer session:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getData();
```

This returns:

```
array(
    [_session_validator_data] => Array
        (
            [remote_addr] => <MY IP>
            [http_via] => 
            [http_x_forwarded_for] => <MY IP>
            [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
        )

    [session_hosts] => Array
            (
                [bestevalue.info] => 1
            )
    [messages] => Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection Object
            (
                [_messages:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_lastAddedMessage:protected] => 
            )
    [id] => 
)
```

I am logged in, can see the customer dashboard with customer info on it but not able to use that session in my custom module.

Please guide me how to fix this.

Update:

I have checked in `/app/etc/local.xml` that session type is file

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
```

So is there different method of extracting session info with PHP? What am I doing wrong?

**Update 2:**

i have used router as well to make pretty url

`public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)`

on start of this action i placed

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));`

but still not working with router without one it is working for example directly accessing the action :

`site.com/module/controller/action`

it works but not with router. any thoughts? thanks,

Comment: I assume that the general user login is working (i.e. your customer can access the personal user page?) - then it can not be a problem with the session storage.

Comment: yes its working i can see my dashboard with info

Comment: What class are you extending in your module? It could be that you are extending an admin area class and thats where the issue stems from

Comment: my controllers extends this class Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action

Comment: In which place / file are you making the above calls?

Comment: above calls were made in /app/code/local/Namespace/Module/controllers/IndexController.php within methodAction()

Comment: You write on the live site it is not working - is it working properly on a test / dev machine? That would mean a server config issue or something like that.

Comment: yes on test/dev its all working normally but its on the client (live) site where is this unexpected problem is.

Comment: Any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

What is the point of the second parameter in `Mage::getSingleton()`? This info would be passed to the constructor of the `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` class, but this constructor does not take arguments:

Replacing this by

```
$sessCustomer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
```

should work.

I assume, that you added your

```
var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getData());
```

after this error-nous call which could have destroyed the session in your module.

Comment: replaced but still the same result. acutaly it was all part of what i tried so far. i have tried em separately.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered by not getting the customer session inside my custom module. It was working in my localhost fine but in server i couldn't able to get the customer session.

I have found the solution by replacing the frontname in config.xml,

i have just changed `<frontName>votingsytem</frontName> to <frontName>vote</frontName>`

i got the customer session it work fine in live server.

I hope this will be useful.

**Before:**

```
<frontend>
  <routers>
     <votingsytem>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
           <module>Vgs_Votingsytem</module>
           <frontName>votingsytem</frontName>
        </args>
     </votingsytem>        
  </routers>
  <layout>
     <updates>
        <votingsytem>
           <file>votingsytem.xml</file>
        </votingsytem>
     </updates>
  </layout>
```

**After:**

```
<frontend>
  <routers>
     <votingsytem>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
           <module>Vgs_Votingsytem</module>
           <frontName>vote</frontName>
        </args>
     </votingsytem>        
  </routers>
  <layout>
     <updates>
        <votingsytem>
           <file>votingsytem.xml</file>
        </votingsytem>
     </updates>
  </layout>
```